# Terminate Thread in hidden code for CANBus adapter

Tags: c#, multithreading, terminate, abort

I am working with a [CANBus adapter](http://www.easysync-ltd.com/product/530/usb2-f-1001.html) while currently writing code for it in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I am trying to make a GUI that runs a separate thread for reading in messages from a TEKTRONIX 020-2924-XX DPO DEMO 2 board via the CANBus serial adapter.

I have tried to figure out the safe way to terminate the thread (called setReceiveCallBackThread). However, this particular thread is special in that the code of the thread is not available. It is part of a CANBus API.

I have searched around the web (especially stack overflow) on how to safely stop threads. I have discovered using the abort method should always be a last resort.

So if I decide I cannot use abort on a thread, I would have to use exception handling in the canplus_setReceiveCallBack subroutine. However, the problem is I cannot access canplus_setReceiveCallBack; the code is hidden. Remember, this is a unique situation since I CANNOT access the code. Unlike all other situations where the code of the callback function could be seen, the code in this subroutine cannot be seen.

The code below should be everything you need to analyze the problem and hopefully come up with an alternative to using Abort() on the thread.

```
// CANSnifferForm.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class CANSnifferForm : Form
    {

        // per the api document. "This is a blocking call and must be called on a separate thread."
        // the code previously after setCallback... was never being reached because the call is blocking.
        // this calls the setCallbackThread function in another thread so processing can continue.
        Thread setReceiveCallBackThread;
        bool stop;

        int can; // Return value of canplus_open

        uint idFilter; // Filter values entered by user
        ulong lenFilter; 
        bool stopThread; // Used for stopping thread         

        public CANSnifferForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             del = new EASYSYNC.CallbackDelegate(callback);
        }


        private void callback(ref EASYSYNC.CANMsg msg)
        {
            // Populate the dataGridView
            if(InvokeRequired)
               BeginInvoke(del, msg);
            else
               this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(msg.id, msg.len, msg.data, msg.timestamp);
        }

        private EASYSYNC.CallbackDelegate del;

        private void StartRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN closed");
            this.ProcessStatusBox.Clear();
            this.ProcessStatusBox.AppendText("Stopped");
            EASYSYNC.CANMsg msg = new EASYSYNC.CANMsg();
            msg.id = 1;
            msg.timestamp = 2;
            msg.flags = 3;
            msg.len = 4;
            msg.data = 5;

            // Attempt to open CANBus adapter
            can = EASYSYNC.canplus_Open(IntPtr.Zero, "1000", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            if (can < 0)
            {
                // CANBus Adapter not opened
                this.ErrorBox.Clear();
                this.ErrorBox.AppendText("Error opening CAN");
                return;
            }

            // CANBus Adapter successfully opened
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN open");

            // Initialize thread
            setReceiveCallBackThread = new Thread(() => EASYSYNC.canplus_setReceiveCallBack(can, del));

            // Attempt for CANBus adapter to listen
            if (EASYSYNC.canplus_Listen(can) < 0)
            {
                // CANBus Adapter not listening
                this.ErrorBox.Clear();
                this.ErrorBox.AppendText("Error setting listen mode\n");
                EASYSYNC.canplus_Close(can);
                this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
                this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN closed");
                return;
            }

            // CANBus Adapter successfully listening
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
            this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN Listening\n");

            // Place thread in background. Then start it
            setReceiveCallBackThread.IsBackground = true; 
            setReceiveCallBackThread.Start(); 
            while(!setReceiveCallBackThread.IsAlive);

            this.ProcessStatusBox.Clear();
            this.ProcessStatusBox.AppendText("Running\n");       


        }

        private void FilterData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           setReceiveCallBackThread.Abort(); // Stop thread
           while (setReceiveCallBackThread.IsAlive == true)
           {

           }

           this.ProcessStatusBox.Clear();
           this.ProcessStatusBox.AppendText("Stopped");


           // Attempt to flush CANBus Adapter
           if (EASYSYNC.canplus_Flush(can) < 0)
           {
               // CANBus not flushing
               this.ErrorBox.Clear();
               this.ErrorBox.AppendText("Error flushing CAN");
               EASYSYNC.canplus_Close(can); // Close CANBus Adapter
               this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
               this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN closed");
               return;
           }
            // Attempt to reset CANBus Adapter
           if (EASYSYNC.canplus_Reset(can) < 0)
           {
               // CANBus not resetting
               this.ErrorBox.Clear();
               this.ErrorBox.AppendText("Error resetting CAN");
               EASYSYNC.canplus_Close(can); // Close CANBus Adapter
               this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
               this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN closed");
               return;
           }

           this.CANSnifferStatusBox.Clear();
           this.CANSnifferStatusBox.AppendText("CAN closed");
           this.ErrorBox.Clear();
        }

        private void FilterID_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void FilterLength_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void FilterID_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FilterIDBox.MaskFull)
            {

            }
            else if (e.Position == FilterIDBox.Mask.Length)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void FilterLength_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FilterLengthBox.MaskFull)
            {

            }
            else if (e.Position == FilterLengthBox.Mask.Length)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My original answer was incorrect, check the edit.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of code fits a category that's very hard to deal with.  Any kind of industrial bus interface callable from .NET is actually implemented in native code.  COM is boilerplate.  Aborting such code is a no-go, only managed code can be aborted in a consistent way.  The underlying winapi call is WaitForSingleObjectEx(), it takes a bAlertable argument.  Everybody either uses the non-Ex version or passes FALSE.  You'll have to give up assuming this is possible.

Comment: If it is indeed blocking on a WaitFor and cannot be stopped, set the `Thread.IsBackgroundThread` property to true so that it will be terminated when the application exits.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was incorrect. According to the API Guide

> Define a function that will receive a callback on all incoming
>   messages. This is a blocking call and must be called on a separate
>   thread. To deregister this callback function, the
>   canplus_setReceiveCallback can be called with cbfn equal to NULL.

The document doesn't say when the blocked call will exit, so my guess is that it exits when you call canplus_setReceiveCallback with NULL.

I don't have a way to test it easily, but you can verify this by outputing text when the original call returns.

```
setReceiveCallBackThread = new Thread(() => { EASYSYNC.canplus_setReceiveCallBack(can, del); Trace.WriteLine("EASYSYNC thread terminated"); });
```

Your Stop_Click method can stop the thread with:

```
EASYSYNC.canplus_setReceiveCallBack(can, null);
```

Comment: The thread doesn't seem to stop unless I physically do a hard disconnect of the CANBUs and Demoboard with the computer. I have even used logic making sure that the code will only proceed if the thread is done. I don't think there is really much else I can do. But I thank you as usual. Your answers are very helpful!!